# PDO not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have the follow PDO:

```
// Connect to PDO / $this->link = PDO
$this->statement = $this->link->prepare("
    SELECT p.*, pm.*
      FROM dev_permissions p, dev_permissions_menu pm
     WHERE pm.id = p.permission_menu_id
       AND pm.module = 'account'
       AND pm.controller IN('login', '*')
       AND pm.action IN('index', '*')
");
// Execute and verify number of rows
```

Which works, returning one row from `$this->statement->rowCount()`.

But, trying to bind params does not work as expected:

```
// Connect to PDO / $this->link = PDO
$this->statement = $this->link->prepare("
    SELECT p.*, pm.*
      FROM dev_permissions p, dev_permissions_menu pm
     WHERE pm.id = p.permission_menu_id
       AND pm.module = :module
       AND pm.controller IN(:controller, '*')
       AND pm.action IN(:action, '*')
",

$this->statement->bindParam(':module', 'account', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$this->statement->bindParam(':controller', 'login', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$this->statement->bindParam(':action', 'index', PDO::PARAM_STR);
// Execute and verify number of rows
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Changed `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to `PDO::PARAM_STR` because CTRL + C/CTRL + V issues, and `#__` to reflect correct database prefix.

Tested with the follow code:

```
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost', 'user', 'password');
$statement = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT p.*, pm.*
      FROM dev_permissions p, dev_permissions_menu pm
     WHERE pm.id = p.permission_menu_id
       AND pm.module = :module
       AND pm.controller IN(:controller, '*')
       AND pm.action IN(:action, '*')
");
$statement->bindParam(':module', $request['module'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':controller', $request['controller'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':action', $request['action'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();

new \Core\Debug($statement->fetchAll());
```

And all works correctly. I can't find the problem with the other way..

Comment: It happens that `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and `PDO::PARAM_STR` both have the integer value 2, but you you ought to be using the correct constants.

Comment: I dont know both use same id, but, from my code, I have `PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: @Michael Thanks for help! Solved my problem changing bindParam to bindValue, because I am binding from a loop, so, bindParam allow only by reference values, which is not the cause inside a foreach.

Answer (score 1):

The variable names are a little confusing in your example ... `prepare` is a method of the PDO object and it returns a PDOStatement Object ... try:

```
$sth = $this->statement->prepare("
    SELECT p.*, pm.*
      FROM #__permissions p, #__permissions_menu pm
    WHERE pm.id = p.permission_menu_id
     AND pm.module = :module
     AND pm.controller IN(:controller, '*')
     AND pm.action IN(:action, '*')
",

$sth->bindParam(':module', 'account', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':controller', 'login', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':action', 'index', PDO::PARAM_STR);

//execute the prepared statement
$sth->execute();
```

As a note ... `rowCount` on a select statement doesn't issue you're query ... it performs a `COUNT(*)` query with the same info as your select ... see example #2 at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Sorry, because I need to "minify" my code, to avoid confusions, I have made another confusion. Updated my revised code, to reflect my actual development code xD

Comment: In that case, are you doing any error checking? Any errors being returned or exceptions being thrown?

Comment: `$this->statement->errorInfo()` return nothing more then sucess (error code `00000`)

Comment: `var_dump($this->_statement->fetchAll());` return empty array: `array
  empty`

Comment: Thanks for help! Solved my problem changing bindParam to bindValue, because I am binding from a loop, so, bindParam allow only by reference values, which is not the cause inside a foreach.